# Adding <integer> seconds to a <timestamp> in PostgreSQL

Tags: time, casting, timedelta

I have a table of items with the following columns:

- `start_time` column (`timestamp without time zone`)
- `expiration_time_seconds` column (`integer`)

For example, some values are:

```
SELECT start_time, expiration_time_seconds 
   FROM whatever 
       ORDER BY start_time;

         start_time         | expiration_time_seconds
----------------------------+-------------------------
 2014-08-05 08:23:32.428452 |                  172800
 2014-08-10 09:49:51.082456 |                    3600
 2014-08-13 13:03:56.980073 |                    3600
 2014-08-21 06:31:38.596451 |                    3600
 ...
```

How do I add the expiration time, given in seconds, to the start_time?

I have tried to format a time interval string for the `interval` command, but failed:

```
blah=> SELECT interval concat(to_char(3600, '9999'), ' seconds');
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: SELECT interval concat(to_char(3600, '9999'), ' seconds');
```

Answer (score 107):

The [trick](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/9636.1098673912@sss.pgh.pa.us) is to create a fixed interval and multiply it with the number of seconds in the column:

```
SELECT start_time, 
       expiration_time_seconds, 
       start_time + expiration_time_seconds * interval '1 second'
FROM whatever 
ORDER BY start_time;

        start_time          | expiration_time_seconds |          end_time
----------------------------|-------------------------|----------------------------
 2014-08-05 08:23:32.428452 |                  172800 | 2014-08-07 08:23:32.428452
 2014-08-10 09:49:51.082456 |                    3600 | 2014-08-10 10:49:51.082456
 2014-08-13 13:03:56.980073 |                    3600 | 2014-08-13 14:03:56.980073
 2014-08-21 06:31:38.596451 |                    3600 | 2014-08-21 07:31:38.596451
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you add space to `start_time + expiration_time_seconds` to make it easy to visualize?

Comment: @bonafernando not sure I understand

Comment: I tried to edit his answer, but the amount of changes were so little I couldn't submit, then I added the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 9.5 it is possible to create interval with `make_interval` function like this:

```
make_interval(secs => 10)
```

also intervals can be added to timestamps easily with `+` operand:

```
start_time + make_interval(secs => 10)
```

it will add 10 seconds to `start_time` and return a new timestamp