# Convert oracle query to postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle

I need to convert oracle query to postgresql

```
(select PK_, 
        'Statement of Holdings' as NOTIFICATIONNAME_ , 
        CASE NOTIFICATIONSSTATUS_ 
             WHEN 'Processed'              THEN 'Succeeded' 
             WHEN 'Processed With Failure' THEN 'Failed' 
             WHEN 'Impacted'               THEN 'Succeeded'  
             WHEN 'Impact Failed'          THEN 'Failed' 
             WHEN 'Archived'               THEN 'Succeeded' 
             WHEN 'Prepared'               THEN 'Running' 
                                           ELSE 'Planned' 
        END as STATUS , 
        DIRECTION_, 
        UPDATEDATE_ as updatedate_, 
        (to_date('19700101', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) + (( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000) * UPDATEDATE_)) as MODIFICATIONDATE  
from atementOfHoldingsNotification_ 
where (DIRECTION_ is not null) and (updatedate_ > 1609462800000) ) 

union all 

(select PK_, 
        'Statement of Transactions' as NOTIFICATIONNAME_ , 
        CASE NOTIFICATIONSSTATUS_  
             WHEN 'Processed'              THEN 'Succeeded' 
             WHEN 'Processed With Failure' THEN 'Failed' 
             WHEN 'Impacted'               THEN 'Succeeded'  
             WHEN 'Impact Failed'          THEN 'Failed' 
             WHEN 'Archived'               THEN 'Succeeded' 
             WHEN 'Prepared'               THEN 'Running' 
                                           ELSE 'Planned' 
        END as STATUS , 
        DIRECTION_, 
        UPDATEDATE_ as updatedate_, 
        (to_date('19700101', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) + (( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000) * UPDATEDATE_)) as MODIFICATIONDATE  
from entOfTransactionsNofitication_ 
where (DIRECTION_ is not null) and (updatedate_ > 1609462800000)) 

union all 

(select PK_, 
        'Statement of Pending Transactions' as NOTIFICATIONNAME_ , 
        CASE NOTIFICATIONSSTATUS_ 
             WHEN 'Processed'              THEN 'Succeeded' 
             WHEN 'Processed With Failure' THEN 'Failed' 
             WHEN 'Impacted'               THEN 'Succeeded'  
             WHEN 'Impact Failed'          THEN 'Failed' 
             WHEN 'Archived'               THEN 'Succeeded' 
             WHEN 'Prepared'               THEN 'Running'
                                           ELSE 'Planned' 
        END as STATUS , 
        DIRECTION_, 
        UPDATEDATE_ as updatedate_,
```

I got this issue when i executed:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: date + numeric
> LINE 4: ..._, (to_date('19700101', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) + (( 1 / 2...
> ^
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> SQL state: 42883
> Character: 586

Comment: As it's currently written, your query won't work neither in oracle because doesn't end properly. Also looks like there are lots of repetitions inside your subqueries, maybe this can be simplified a lot. Can you share your sample data, expected output and a description of what your code is supposed to do?

Comment: What is MODIFICATIONDATE ? And why such complex code for a simple calculation on a date or timestamp?

Comment: Hi @lemon i need to convert this to postgresql any help please ? to_javadate(trunc(current_timestamp))

Comment: @FrankHeikens I have had a look at the question myself. Turns out I think I can answer yours instead. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305135/oracle-convert-unix-epoch-time-to-date). Not the ideal way to do it though, [this](https://database.guide/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-a-date-value-in-oracle/) looks like a much better method to me.

Comment: `date + 1` in Oracle means adding 1 day to a date. In PostgreSQL you can do `date + interval '1 day'`

Comment: I need to convert  to_javadate(trunc(current_timestamp)) to postgresql please

Comment: Your updatedate_ field appears to be an elapsed number of seconds.  If that is so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528028/adding-integer-seconds-to-a-timestamp-in-postgresql

Comment: Date + 1 also works in PostgreSQL for integers

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```sql
to_date('19700101', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) + (( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000) * UPDATEDATE_
```

You can use `TIMESTAMP` and `INTERVAL` literals:

```sql
TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC' + UPDATEDATE_ * INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND
```

Which works in both Oracle [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IYKGJ-ed) and PostgreSQL [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/awLzWeSf).