# SQLite strftime and datetime conversation for PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, epoch

I've tried finding an answer to this question but haven't been entirely successful (or maybe I just don't understand the PostgreSQL documentation).

I am using this function in SQLite:

```
datetime (message.date / 1000000000 + strftime ("%s", "2001-01-01"), "unixepoch", "localtime")
```

message.date is a large integer that can be converted to a date starting in 1987 e.g. **550535817000000000**

strftime gives me **978307200**

I am attempting to recreate this function in postgresql but am definitely missing something because I keep getting errors or incorrect output. A few attempts are below:

```
// Gives SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone + timestamp with time zone
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 51

TO_TIMESTAMP((message.date / 1000000000)) + TO_TIMESTAMP('2001-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD HR24:MI:SS')
```

```
// Date in 1987 with TZ -7 e.g. 1987-05-12 16:36:38.000 -0700
TO_TIMESTAMP((message.date / 1000000000))

// 2001-01-01 00:00:00.000 -0800
TO_TIMESTAMP('2001-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD HR24:MI:SS'),
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something. Can anyone help direct me to the right solution?

**UPDATE:**
The solution below based on @matbalie 's feedback -- this date is based on Messages `chat.db` date in the `message` table.

```
to_timestamp((message.date / 1000000000)::integer + EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM '2001-01-01'::date)::integer) message_date,
```

Comment: You can't add timestamps to each other. Try adding seconds to a timestamp. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28528029/53341

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.

Anyone looking for the answer I found based on this (Messages chat.db date):


to_timestamp((message.date / 1000000000)::integer + EXTRACT(EPOCH

Comment: Why is `message.date` not defined as `timestamp`? Then you could get rid of all that clunky conversion code.

Comment: That's a valid question @a_horse_with_no_name. It is because this database was converted from sqlite to postgres via pgloader and since it's the database was created by Apple for the Messages app, they stored the timestamp in nano-seconds as an integer.